# How to install adb tools on Linux with no GUI?

Tags: adb, linux

I need to use the adb command on my Linux machine which does not have a GUI. Is it possible to install SDK tools without a GUI? I am using Debian 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command-line, you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

<sup>Source: [Installing ADB and Fastboot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/Debugging/Installing_ADB).</sup>

<sup>Note: If you're already logged as `root`, you can skip `sudo`.</sup>

Comment: I get 404 after running apt-get update https://pastebin.com/W8NSzqXW